# blob image render in spring mvc 3.0

Tags: spring, jsp, servlets

I am trying to read blob type image which is coming from Database. My method in controller. Only Image file is displaying on JSP nothing else

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showDetails")
public ModelAndView showDetails(@RequestParam("doc") int id,
        HttpServletResponse responce) {
    ModelAndView mView = new ModelAndView();
    File file = documentDao.getFileDetail(id);
    byte[] bytes = null;
    try {
        OutputStream op = responce.getOutputStream();
        int length = (int) file.getContent().length();
        bytes = file.getContent().getBytes(1, length);
        op.write(bytes);
        op.flush();
        op.close();
        responce.setContentType("image/gif");
        mView.addObject("image", op);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    mView.addObject("file", file);
    mView.setViewName("filedetails");
    return mView;
}
```

The above method in my controller class. And I want to render image as well as some text on JSP. But only image is coming in Browser.

Comment: i am unable to format this code. Sorry for facing problem in reading/understanding the code.

Comment: what else do you want to display other than the image?

Comment: I want to display some text.
the filedetails.jsp -->  <c:out value="${file}"></c:out>
<c:if test="${! empty file}">
<c:out value="${file.id}"></c:out><br>
<c:out value="${file.name}"></c:out>----
<c:out value="${file.descrition}"></c:out><br>
<c:out value="${file.content}"></c:out>
</c:if>
<img src="${image}" height="10" width="10" align="right">

Comment: the answer given by @Slava Semushin is correct. If your image isn't rendering, probably the path to it is incorrect. E.g. if you are running in a context, you shouldn't use `/image?` but `/yourapp/image?` (or better - use `<c:url`)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it this way in Spring (in Servlets more precisely). Create two different controllers -- one will serve image and another will return JSP page with text. To get image at page just properly set value of `src` attribute of `img` tag: it should point to first controller.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Could you please give me idea or example, how can i call image controller through my jsp page. your help would be help full for me.

Comment: Hi, I make new method for display image in controller.
 @RequestMapping("/images/{imageid}")
 @ResponseBody
 public void image(@PathVariable("image_id") long id){
  
  int image_id = (int)id;
  System.out.println(image_id);
 }

And in JSP image tag is 
<img id="image_id" src="<c:url value="/images/${file.id}" />" height="10" width="10" align="right">

But my method(image) is not calling in controller class.

Comment: When you call `System.out.println` the output goes to standart output (to server's log file in your case) and not to client side. To show image to client you should get output stream and print to it (also don't forget to set right headers). See following article for details: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html

Comment: Could you please share your gmail-id ? 
I can share with you my current problem. Now i am not able to call any simple servlet or any method in controller class (where i used annotation {@RequestMapping}). Please if you will share your id it would be easy for me.

Comment: What is "gmail-id"? Are you talking about e-mail address? It should be shown in my profile, just click on my nick.